# "Who's Taller" game with random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have an exercise that I cant get my head around.

You play the game of who's taller" in class (of n people). You pick always a random
opponent among the people you haven't yet played, compare your heights, and the taller
person wins (height are never exactly the same). You continue until your first loss or until you beat everyone. By the time you are finished, you won X games. What is the mass
function of X, so what is P(X=i) for i = 0, 1, 2,..., n-1

Hint: Solve it for small class sizes first. Don't assume anything about your or other people's heights.

The thing is, it seems too simple if I solve for small classes - like size 2 or 3. I always get P(X=i) = 1/n

Comment: How do you get $P(X=i)=\frac{1}{n}$? The question in `What is the probability that I win this round?` You can either be smaller or taller than your opponent, without any assumptions about either size, your chance to win *this round* is $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: The question is - what is the probability that I win X rounds before I lose

Comment: Go step after step: What is the probability to win *the current round*? It is $\frac{1}{2}$. The same applies for *not wining the current round*. Now, what does it mean to *win i rounds*? It means to *win* $i$ times and *lose* then. So it is for example $P(X=0) = \frac{1}{2}$, $P(X=1) = \frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2}$ etc.

Comment: As a side note, to make no assumptions about heights at all, you can also substitute $\frac{1}{2}$ with $p$ (probability to win) and $1-p$ (probability to *not* win).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are yourself chosen uniformly randomly from the class (a feature which we will assume but that you do not explain), $[X\geqslant i]$ means that you are the tallest person from a uniform sample of size $i+1$ (you and your $i$ first "opponents"). By symmetry the probability of that event is $1/(i+1)$ hence $P(X\geqslant i)=1/(i+1)$ for every $0\leqslant i\leqslant n$.

Surely you can deduce $P(X=i)$ from these considerations?

Comment: Thank you, this is amazing. But why is the (1/2)^n answer wrong then?

Comment: You mean, the one in the comments by user @Lukas? Because each time you win, your chances of winning again do not stay at .5 but *decrease*. Consider that you already won against some people hence they were statistically biased towards small heights and the remaining sample is made of statistically taller people than at the beginning.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much, I understand it now